# Can I count "Calls" on Contacts associated with an Opportunity?

Tags: trigger, count

We had an existing TaskTrigger that counted "completed calls" on Leads which was pretty straight-forward. I modified the code and now it counts "completed calls" on Opportunities. Our sales manager would also like that count to include calls on Contacts, which are linked to an Account to that Opportunity.

If anyone could provide some assistance that would be awesome. Here's the existing trigger code

```
Trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after insert) { 

    // If triggered by a task on a Lead we get WhoID
    Set<ID> whoids = new Set<ID>();
    // If triggered by a task on an Opportunity we get a WhatID
    Set<ID> whatids = new Set<ID>();

    For ( Task t : Trigger.New )
    {
        whoids.Add(t.WhoID);
        whatids.Add(t.WhatID);
    }

    Map<ID,Lead> leads = New Map<ID,Lead> ([Select ID,Dials__c, (Select ID From Tasks where subject like '%Call%' and status = 'Completed' ) From Lead Where ID IN : whoids]);
    Map<ID,Opportunity> opps = New Map<ID,Opportunity> ([Select ID,Calls__c, (Select ID From Tasks where subject like '%Call%' and status = 'Completed' ) From Opportunity Where ID IN : whatids]);


    // My comment
    For ( ID id : whoids )
    {
        if(id != null) {
            System.Debug('whoid: ' + id);
            // Leads
            if (String.valueOf(id).startsWith('00Q'))
            {
                List<Task> tsks = leads.Get(id).Tasks;
                leads.Get(id).Dials__c= tsks.Size(); 
            }
        }
    }

    For ( ID id : whatids )
    {
        if(id != null) {
            System.Debug('whatid: ' + id);
            // Opportunities
            if (String.valueOf(id).startsWith('006'))
            {
                List<Task> tsks = opps.Get(id).Tasks;
                opps.Get(id).Calls__c= tsks.Size(); 
            }
        }
    }

    Update leads.Values();
    Update opps.Values();
}
```

I have this set for Opportunity Contact Role

[image]

Comment: are you using OpportunityContactRole to relate Contacts to Oppos? If not, counting Tasks on a Contact won't know which Opportunity to update as Contacts belong to an Account and Accounts have 1+ Oppos

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to SF development so I'm not sure. Where can I look in SF to see if I'm using the OpportunityContactRole to relate Contacts to Oppos? Thanks!!

Comment: I added an image crop1645...is this what you were referring to?

Comment: there is a related list at the bottom of the Oppo detail page; there is also a standard report on Opportunities with Contacts

Comment: the picture you included is from Setup -- what is more relevant is whether users are populating the relationship

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to modify your trigger on Task to count Call tasks against the Task's Contact's Opportunity, you have to know which Opportunity the Contact belongs to. Since by default, a Contact belongs to an Account, and an Account could have many Opportunities, it is not so obvious for the code to know which Opportunity to assign the count to.

Some options

1. Exploit `OpportunityContactRole` - this is an OOB junction object between Contact and Opportunity. It must be populated by the user when an Opportunity is created/updated in order for this to be useful. SFDC doesn't enforce the relationship. Even here, there could be several Opportunities associated with one Contact and you might want to choose the earliest open one or all open ones.
2. Make an assumption that any call Task for a Contact applies to the earliest open Opportunity for that Contact's Account in the current quarter or later.  If this works for you, modifying the existing trigger is just a matter of finding that Opportunity